# linux regex matching chracter ß

Tags: regex, linux

I am running into something I could not see in Linux.  Can any one tell me why the first regex is not picking up the "ß-carotene"?

```
$ cat cmpg
ß-Cyclopentyl-4-(7H-pyrrolo[2,3-d]pyrimidin-4-yl)-((3R)-1H-pyrazole-1-propanenitrile
ß-Cyclopentyl-4-(7H-pyrrolo[2,3-d]pyrimidin-4-yl)-((R)-1H-pyrazole-1-propanenitrile
ß-carotene  

$ cat cmpg|awk  '/[^\w\s({)}\r\n\[\]],/'
ß-Cyclopentyl-4-(7H-pyrrolo[2,3-d]pyrimidin-4-yl)-((3R)-1H-pyrazole-1-propanenitrile
ß-Cyclopentyl-4-(7H-pyrrolo[2,3-d]pyrimidin-4-yl)-((R)-1H-pyrazole-1-propanenitrile

cat cmpg|awk  '/ß/'
ß-Cyclopentyl-4-(7H-pyrrolo[2,3-d]pyrimidin-4-yl)-((3R)-1H-pyrazole-1-propanenitrile
ß-Cyclopentyl-4-(7H-pyrrolo[2,3-d]pyrimidin-4-yl)-((R)-1H-pyrazole-1-propanenitrile
ß-carotene
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I can recreate his results on OS X and Linux.

Comment: because the last line of cmpg doesn't contain a comma `,` ?

Comment: @TimPietzcker : You probably have a unicode input file, so you need to make sure that awk understand (and matches for) unicode. Try setting LC_ALL=....  (the right unicode setting)

Comment: Incidentally you are using the **wrong letter**. You want “β” (GREEK SMALL LETTER BETA) but you are using “ß” (LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S).

Answer (score 8):

```
$ cat cmpg|awk  '/[^\w\s({)}\r\n\[\]],/'
```

only matches lines that contain at least one comma.

As for why the negated character class matches the `2` (which puzzled me because `\w` contains all ASCII digits, thus `[^\w...]` should fail to match `2`): `awk` uses POSIX basic regular expressions that don't know the `\w` (or  `\s`)  shorthands. You would need to use `[:alnum:]` or `[:space:]` instead.

All in all, that regex *is* strange in any regex flavor. What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: ... and some character not in the negated character class in front of the comma (nitpicking)

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat cmpg|awk  '/[^\w\s({)}\r\n\[\]],/'
```

looks for any string which have 2 characters:

- the first character shoud NOT (`[^`) be :

  - `\w` : a "word" character (digits, alphanumerical, and underscore)

    - OR a literral `w` if that awk version doesn't know about `\w` special meaning
  - `\s` : a whitespace (could be a Lot of things if using unicode, not just space and tab)

    - OR a literral `s` if that awk version doesn't know about `\s` special meaning
  - `(`  : a `(`
  - `{`  : a `{`
  - `)`  : a `)`
  - `}`  : a `}`
  - `\r` : a linefeed
  - `\n` : a newline
  - `\[` : a `[`
  - `\]` : a `]`
- the 2nd character HAVE to be :

  - `,` : a `,` (comma).

The last line does NOT contain a comma. (the Beta would match, otherwise, as it's not part of the above list)

Comment: But why does the second line match?

Comment: your input file is probably unicode, and awk sees soemthing else than a "2" ? Try to check if that awk can handle unicode, and if it can, make sure it's invoked with the right locales ` cat cmpg | LC_ALL=...  awk '.....'` . I am not very specific, but ymmv (depends on which awk you use, which locales you have, which locales the file is written with. utf-8 ? something else?)

Comment: OR it's a versino of awk that doesn't know about `\w` and therefore sees it as a literral `w` ? Try to edit the 2nd line to be "w" instead of "2", and if it doesn't match anymore, it's because "\w" was interpreted as "w"

Comment: Ah, I've just found out the same thing. Only `gawk` knows those shorthands.

Comment: You could switch to Perl to avoid most portability problems of regexps (but even then, some versions of Perl could (not sure) have different options or different handling of complex character codes...)